# Continue yes/no and resetting the int x to a new value in Java?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am making a grade converter. The objective is to enter your grade as a percentage and then it will tell you your letter grade.  Then at the end it ask continue y/n.  If you say yes it will ask you again to enter you numerical grade and so forth any you can convert it again.  I'm having a problem with once I enter a value for the numerical grade it stays that value and doesn't ask you to enter the numerical grade again.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Doc2
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Welcome to Leter Grade Converter"); //Wellcome User
System.out.println(); //Blake Space
System.out.println("Enter numerical grade: "); //Promt user for input

int x;
x = sc.nextInt();

{
        if (x <= 100 && x >= 90) {
            System.out.println("Letter grade: A");
        }

        if(x <= 89 && x >= 80) {
            System.out.println("Letter grade: B");
        }

        if(x <= 79 && x >= 70) {
            System.out.println("Letter grade: C");
        }

        if(x <=69 && x >=60) {
            System.out.println("Letter grade: D");
        }

        if(x <=50 && x >=0) {
            System.out.println("Letter grade: F");
 }


String choice = "y";
while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
{


    if (x <= 100 && x >= 90) {
        System.out.println("Letter grade: A");
    }

    if(x <= 89 && x >= 80) {
        System.out.println("Letter grade: B");
    }

    if(x <= 79 && x >= 70) {
        System.out.println("Letter grade: C");
    }

    if(x <=69 && x >=60) {
        System.out.println("Letter grade: D");
    }

    if(x <=50 && x >=0) {
        System.out.println("Letter grade: F");
    }

System.out.println ("Continue? (y/n): ");
choice = sc.next();
System.out.println();

} //end while
} //end main() method
}
}
```

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: *"once I enter a value for the numerical grade it stays that value and doesn't ask you to enter the numerical grade again"* ... Your not asking for the grade _inside_ the loop, so isn't the issue obvious?

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144380/how-do-i-create-a-while-loop-around-a-for-loop-that-will-allow-the-user-to-quit/40144456#40144456

Comment: the reason I am not asking for the grade in the loop is because when I did that I made a infinite loop that repeated "enter numerical value" over and over again

Comment: `do { ... } while (response.toLowerCase.equals("yes"));` or some such

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your grade input into your loop, otherwise it'll keep using the same `x` value:

```
String choice = "y";
while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
    int x = sc.nextInt();

    if (x <= 100 && x >= 90) {
        System.out.println("Letter grade: A");
    }
    //...

    System.out.println ("Continue? (y/n): ");
    choice = sc.next();
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a do-while loop. So that your code will definitely run the first time. Then when the user enters 'y' it will run again. Change your code like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.println("Welcome to Leter Grade Converter");//Wellcome User
     System.out.println(); //Blake Space
     do{
         System.out.println("Enter numerical grade: "); //Promt user for input

         int x;
         x = sc.nextInt();

        if (x <= 100 && x >= 90) {
            System.out.println("Letter grade: A");
        }

        if(x <= 89 && x >= 80) {
            System.out.println("Letter grade: B");
        }

        if(x <= 79 && x >= 70) {
            System.out.println("Letter grade: C");
        }

        if(x <=69 && x >=60) {
            System.out.println("Letter grade: D");
        }

        if(x <=50 && x >=0) {
            System.out.println("Letter grade: F");
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue(y/n)?");
        String choice=sc.nextLine();
    }while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
}
```

This way everytime the program will prompt the user to enter the value for x and the value for choice variable which determines the continuation of the program.